# How to check if input character equal to character in word

Tags: c#, casting

I am trying to check whether the key that the user presses is equal to the key in a word. e.g. the word  is "flower" and the user enters "f" the output should be true, if the user presses "x" the output should be false. When I try to enter a character it give me System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Char[]' to type 'System.IConvertible'.' where the code checks if user input matches key in the word.

```
private bool KeyCheck(char key)
{
    //word arraylist values set to word in array currentWords at index 0
    word.Add((currentWords[0].ToCharArray()));

    for (int i = 0; i < word.Count; i++)
    {
        //checks if user input matches key in word
        if (Convert.ToChar(word[i]) == key)
        {
            correct++;
            return true;
        }                                         
    }

    incorrect++;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Where are `word` and `currentWords[]` defined? You don't show that in your code, so it's not really possible to reproduce the error that you are seeing.

Comment: What's wrong with `return currentWords[0].Contains(key);`? We just check if `key` is int `currentWords[0]` or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private bool KeyCheck(char key)
 {
     return  currentWords[0].Contains(key);
 }
```

Comment: this doesn't take into account his `correct` and `incorrect` counters which are presumably important.  But not too hard to add that in.

Comment: This works, any chance you could explain this code a bit?

Comment: Yes, the Any method is an extension method from the System.Linq , it determines whether any element of a sequence exists or satisfies a condition.  form more details https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-6.0

Comment: It seems that we can put it as `private bool KeyCheck(char key) => currentWords[0].Contains(key);` - why should we use the array?

Comment: yes i will update

Answer (score 0):

If you want just to check if `key` is within `currentWords[0]`, try `Contains`:

```
// Assuming that currentWords[0] is never null
private bool KeyCheck(char key) => currentWords[0].Contains(key);
```

However, as I can see, you have some `correct` and `incorrect` counters; if they must be kept as well as `words` we can use `Contains` again but with some extra logic:

```
private bool KeyCheck(char key) {
  word.Add((currentWords[0].ToCharArray()));

  // Let it be a good old loop; I have put "char[] w", not "var w" 
  // to be evident what's going on 
  foreach (char[] w in words) {
    if (w.Contains(key)) {
      correct++;

      return true;
    }
  }
  
  incorrect++;

  return false;
}
```

Linq solution (we *query* `words`) can be something like this:

```
using System.Linq;

...

private bool KeyCheck(char key) {
  word.Add((currentWords[0].ToCharArray()));

  bool result = words.Any(w => w.Contains(key));

  if (result) 
    correct++;
  else
    incorrect++;

  return result;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

`word[i]` is of type `System.Char[]` like the exception says which can't be converted to a character.  Not sure what type `currentWords` is but if it's a string array then when you add `currentWords[0]` to `word` you can do

`word.Add(Convert.ToChar(currentWords[0]));`

and then your `if` statement would just be

`if (word[i] == key)`